# How to implement electron fluid limit of this point particle model?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, models, semiclassical

I'm interested in modelling a "fluid" of electrons, and I would like to show how it arises from a discrete model, but I'm running into conceptual difficulties when trying to go to the continuum limit. To be precise, I want to go from a semi-classical model of electrons on the real line, each with an associated charge $q$ and "classical spin" $\mathbf s_j$ (of unit length in $\mathbb R^3$), to a continuous model with charge density $\rho(x)$ and spin density $\mathbf s(x)$. (There is also a time parameter, but it will not matter here.)

My approach has been to divide the real line into intervals $I_k = [x_k, x_{k+1})$ of lenght $\Delta x$. Then the average charge density in $I_k$ is given by
$$\langle \rho \rangle_k := \frac{N_k q}{\Delta x},$$
with $N_k$ being the number of particles in $I_k$, and if $J_k$ is the index set of those particles, then the average spin density in $I_k$ is given by
$$\langle \mathbf s \rangle_k = \frac{1}{\Delta x} \sum_{j \in J_k} \mathbf s_j.$$
The idea would then be to go to a continuum limit in which $\rho(x_k)$ can be identified with $\langle \rho \rangle_k$, and $\mathbf s(x_k)$ can be identified with $\langle \mathbf s \rangle_k$.

My issue is the following. To get continuous densities I need $\Delta x \to 0$, but then, in order for $\langle \rho \rangle_k$ to stay finite, I need to let $N_k \to 0$ as well (assuming $q$ is fixed as the fundamental charge). But $N_k$, being a discrete variable, cannot go continuously to 0, and if we let it go to 0 discontinuously, then the expressions for $\langle \rho \rangle_k$ and $\langle \mathbf s \rangle_k$ become identically zero.

I can imagine workarounds such as treating $N_k$ like a contiuous variable (though this would make $J_k$ ill-defined), or holding $N_k$ constant and letting $q \to 0$ (though this would make the number density $\rho/q$ infinite), but those seem terribly ad hoc and problematic.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: After thinking more about it, maybe we can treat $N_k$ as stochastic, as in arising from a statistical mechanics model, and replace $N_k$ with $\langle N_k \rangle$ in the definition of $\langle \rho \rangle_k$? Then noninteger values would make sense. The definition of $\langle \mathbf s \rangle_k$ would then also have to be stochastic, and it is not immediately obvious how one would write it, but it seems to make sense conceptually at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you're jumping from a discrete model into a continuous model you are going to have to accept some problematic situations like the ones you described. The most obvious solution I see is to let $N_k$ be a continuous variable. Yes, $J_k$ will be ill-defined, but you don't longer need it in a fluid model.